# Why is absolute value of negative exponent equal to positive value?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, natural-numbers

I am asked to integrate the following: 
$\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\left\lvert 3x\right\rvert}dx$

And I am told that $e^{-\left\lvert x\right\rvert}=e^{x}$

How is it that an absolute value (the exponent) multiplied by -1 is still equal to a positive number?

Comment: Consider the limits of integration: for all $x<0$, ${-|x|} = x$

Comment: Many years ago, I tutored $2$nd year university engineering calculus for $2$ years. I was amazed that these students could often handle quite complicated $3$D transformations, integrals, etc., but for some reason, the one particular issue they had the most trouble with (at least in terms of asking me) was understanding that if $x \lt 0$, then $-|x| = x$. Note this only involved several students, & I'm not trying to disparage or put them down, as they were very intelligent, but I found it interesting, & perplexing (even now, I don't know why), that they had this particular math "blind" spot.

Comment: @JohnOmielan for me it is just the disconnect in seeing "-x" turn to "x" which usually implies dropping the negative sign altogether, and not realizing that in this case the negative sign will still be there because of the interval

Comment: @blizz What I referred to happened about $30$ years ago, so my recollection is rather limited, but your explanation sounds like it was what those engineering students had an issue with. Thanks for telling me this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your integral is over only negative numbers (and zero). If $x$ is negative, then $|x|$ is positive and $-|x|$ is negative again, so $x=-|x|$. This is of course not true in general, but absolutely fine if you only deal with negative numbers.

Comment: I was overthinking this one... :\

Comment: Easy thing to do! :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $x=-2$. Then $|x| = 2$ and $-|x|= -2 = x$. We know from the bounds of the integral that $x<0$, so the example with $x = -2$ works for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to change $t=-x$ such that the integral is now on positive numbers.

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-|3x|}\mathop{dx}=\int_{+\infty}^0 e^{-|-3t|}(-\mathop{dt})=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-3t}\mathop{dt}$

With now $-|-3t|=-(3t)=-3t$ and the sign before $\mathop{dt}$ is cancelled with reordering the bounds of integration.